Get Package Delays from IBIS R_pin, L_pin, C_pin and length
How can I calculate package delays (ps) from the resistance, capacitance, inductance and internal length (µm) of each pin?
When I asked the component manufacturer for the package delays, they just told me to use the IBIS file. This file has the R, L and C values of each pin, but I also have the internal lengths of each pin in a separate file.
5GHz signals. A component on one end of the transmission line has package delays, the component I'm trying to convert has package lengths. I need both to be the same for my CAD to work, and I think delays would be best for 5GHz signals anyway.
